# Disable Read Out protection STM32

Tags: stm32

I have a STM32WB55 custom board where I put the Read out Protection to level 1. I would like to change it back to level 0 as in this level, I am unable to program the PCB. I have tried using the ST LINK utility and the STM32Prog to change it back to level 0 but to no avail

STLINK Utility:

```
 Could not set Option bytes! 
    Please reset the target and retry. 
    Can not read memory! 
    Disable Read Out Protection and retry.
```

STM32 Prog :

```
Error: Expected value for Option Byte "RDP": 0xAA, found: 0xFF
Error: Option Byte Programming failed
```

From what I read online if my version of STLINK utility is higher than 4.0 it will work but it is not the case. Boot0 is at high and I have try reseting it but to no avail as well. Any ideas on how I can change it back?

Comment: Generally with erasing the entire chip

Comment: @uglyoldbob full chip erase works?

Comment: why don't you try?

Comment: @muyustan ive just tried and I cant as the read out protection prevents it

Comment: Disabling readout protection does a full chip erase.  But then you must FULLY  POWER CYCLE THE BOARD before it takes effect.   To make sure it's not still getting current leakage, disconnect *everything* - SWD, serial, USB, there should be no wires connected to the target at all.

Answer (score 5):

open ST-LINK utility-> go to Target -> Option Bytes
then change the Read Out protection to level 0
Apply, then make a full chip erase.
it has worked for me, hope this helps you

I found the answer in this link
https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/keil-forum/34824/can-t-disable-read-out-protection